# While using Signals & slots in Qt an error is coming

Tags: qt4

Error is: `error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(MainWindow*, const char*, MainWindow*, const char*)'
In second() member function the slot progress() is not matching with the definition.`

So can anyone please solve the problem.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include<QFuture>
#include<QtConcurrentMap>
#include<QtCore>
#include<QString>
int i =0;

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:
    void finished();

public slots:
    void progress(const QString& status);

public:
    void search();
    void second();

};

void MainWindow::progress(const QString& status)
{
    printf("progress bar %d is finished", i);
    i++;
}
void MainWindow::search()
{
    QFuture<void> future=QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::second);
}
void MainWindow::finished()
{
    printf("signal got finished");
}

void MainWindow::second()
{
    MainWindow n,o;
    QObject::connect(&n,SIGNAL(finished()),&o,
                     SLOT(progress(const QString&)));
    o.progress("hello");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mi;
    mi.search();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your class must (not necessarily directly) inherit from `QObject` class (see [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT)).
Furthermore, in your `main()` you should `show()` your widgets
Also, your `connect()` call will fail at runtime, because `Q_SIGNAL` and `Q_SLOT` must have identical set of arguments. If you need to differentiate between signals (add additional parameter) consider using `QSignalMapper` class. See [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsignalmapper.html)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't inherit from QObject delivered class. I gues your MainWindow has to be QMainWindow delivered class